# Bayesian hyperparameter optimization, is it worth it?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, optimization, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

On Goodfellow-et-al-2016,Deep Learning book the following sentence can be found:

"Currently, we cannot unambiguously recommend Bayesian hyperparameter
optimization as an established tool for achieving better deep learning results or
for obtaining those results with less effort. Bayesian hyperparameter optimization
sometimes performs comparably to human experts, sometimes better, but fails
catastrophically on other problems. It may be worth trying to see if it works on a
particular problem but is not yet sufficiently mature or reliable".

> Significant progress occurred?

Personally, I never used Bayesian hyperparameter optimization preferring for simplicity grid search and random search. As a first approximation I'm considering easy AI task as multiclassification problems with DNNs and CNNs.
In which cases should I take it into consideration, is it worth it?

Comment: I have to agree with the author, considering the goal of deep learning largely to make predictions, vice updating from a prior to a posterior. Now Bayes would make prediction intervals for deep learning rather simple, but I have not seen interest in this from the machine learning community.

Comment: @JTH, "Bayesian hyperparameter tuning" is an application of Bayesian ideas to the hyperparameter search itself, not to the structure or purpose of the neural network.

Comment: I work on (theory of) Bayesian optimisation --- there is no evidence for Bayesian optimisation of neural network hyperparameters (learning rates etc) as being a worthwhile approach. State of the art 'accuracy in vision' etc results tend to use genetic algorithms. If you open a bunch of Bayesian optimisation papers and look at the experimental settings, you'll struggle to find anyone trying to pitch their method in the context of any serious neural networks.